# Keras LSTM: how is stated maintained within a single batch?

Tags: lstm, keras

Assuming Keras LSTM will reset internal state after each batch, I want to understand how internal state is maintained within a single batch. Suppose then, *batch_size*=4, *timesteps*=3 and *num_features*=1. The problem is to predict the next element of a univariate timeseries $x_1,x_2, ... ,x_n$.

According to guides, the right way to feed this model  is to prepare overlapping windows of length *timesteps*. Thus, the first batch consists of the following inputs and targets:

input A: [$x_1,x_2,x_3$] $\rightarrow$ target A: $x_4$

input B: [$x_2,x_3,x_4$] $\rightarrow$ target B: $x_5$

input C: [$x_3,x_4,x_5$] $\rightarrow$ target C: $x_6$

input D: [$x_4,x_5,x_6$] $\rightarrow$ target D: $x_7$

Because this is a single batch, the internal state should be maintained throughout. First, the model will process input A using the initial internal state (the state after reset). The new internal state after processing input A will be the internal state produced after processing $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, which I will denote as $h_{3}$. Similarly, the internal states after processing $(x_1)$ and $(x_1,x_2)$ are $h_{1}$ and $h_{2}$, however these are not maintained.

Next, the model will process input B. However, if I understood correctly, it will process input B given an internal state $h_3$. Thus, it will process $(x_2,x_3,x_4)$ given than it has previously seen $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Yet, how could it be that the model has seen $x_3$, as it about to be fed with $x_2$, followed by $x_3$ and $x_4$? In contrary, it makes more sense to me that it should process input B given an internal state $h_{1}$, not  $h_{3}$.

In summary, it seems as if the sequence of internal state is based on a sequence $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_3,x_4,x_5...)$ and not the original sequence $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,...)$. How is this not wrong?

Also, if the network has already been fed with $x_3$ in input A , how can it be fed again two more times with $x_3$ in input B and input C, without messing up the internal state?

Answer (score 0):

If ABCD are given as 4 different observations, then the state will not be consistent between them. If you give one sequence $x_1, x_2, ..., x_t$ and do autoregressive prediction (predict $x_{i+1}$ given $i$ for 1,2,...), the state will be consistent (because there's only 1 input). An easy way to verify this is to write a simple test case comparing the two scenarios.